# How to convert Spring JPA Application to Multi-Tennancy

Tags: java, spring, jpa, eclipselink

I have a Spring JPA / Eclipselink application that I would like to modify for single table tennancy.  This would potentially involve adding an additional TennantID column to each relevant table.  I found [this](http://codecrafters.blogspot.com.au/2013/03/multi-tenant-cloud-applications-with.html) reference on one approach.  In this document the author suggests defining (or similar):

```
public interface CurrentTenantResolver<T extends Serializable> {
    T getCurrentTenantId();
}
 public class ShiroCurrentTenantResolver
        implements CurrentTenantResolver<Long> {
    @Override
    public Long getCurrentTenantId() {
        Session session = SecurityUtils.getSubject().getSession();
        return (Long) session.getAttribute("tenantId");
    }
}
```

and then (torwards the end of the article):

```
Public class MultiTenantJpaTransactionManager extends JpaTransactionManager {

    @Inject
    private CurrentTenantResolver tenantResolver;

    @Override
    protected void doBegin(final Object transaction, final TransactionDefinition definition) {
        super.doBegin(transaction, definition);
        final EntityManagerHolder emHolder = (EntityManagerHolder) TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource(getEntityManagerFactory());
        final EntityManager em = emHolder.getEntityManager();
        final Serializable tenantId = tenantResolver.getCurrentTenantId();
        if (tenantId != null) {
            em.setProperty("eclipselink.tenant-id", tenantId);
        } else {
            // some error handling here
        }
    }
}
```

In my application, I have a JPAConfiguration Class which loads database connection properties, creates beans etc.  One of the beans is the JpaTransactionManager bean (code below).

I am not sure how to modify my JPAConfiguration class to enable the proposed MultiTenantJpaTransactionManager functionality.

I am assuming that if I can get this working then this is possible:

```
@Multitenant(SINGLE_TABLE)
@TenantDiscriminatorColumn(name = "TENANT", contextProperty = "multitenant.id")
```

I apologise if this is a naive question - maybe there is a simpler / cleaner way of doing this?

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories("foo.bar.repository")
@EnableJpaAuditing

@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource(value={"classpath:default.properties"}),
    @PropertySource(value={"file:/foo/bar/server.properties"}, ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
})

public class JPAConfiguration {

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.user";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_LOGGING_LEVEL = "eclipselink.logging.level";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DDL_GENERATION = "eclipselink.ddl-generation";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DDL_GENERATION_OUTPUT_MODE = "eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_JDBC_UPPERCASE_COLUMNS = "eclipselink.jdbc-uppercase-columns";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_WEAVING = "eclipselink.weaving";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "foo.bar.entities";

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(PersistenceProvider.class);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(providerProperties());

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    private Properties providerProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("eclipselink.logging.level", env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_LOGGING_LEVEL));
        properties.put("eclipselink.ddl-generation", env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DDL_GENERATION));
        properties.put("eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode", env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DDL_GENERATION_OUTPUT_MODE));
        properties.put("eclipselink.jdbc-uppercase-columns", env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_JDBC_UPPERCASE_COLUMNS));
        properties.put("eclipselink.weaving", env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_WEAVING));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory()
                .getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe easier to source a multi-tenant JVM like waratek

Comment: Thank you for this.  I will have a look but feels a bit like abstraction on abstraction?